# Connector identification for Avermedia C875

Tags: pcb, identification, connector, surface-mount

I have an AverMedia C875 device, I would like to capture an analog output of my VCR with it. The device has a specific connector for such purposes, but I sadly don't have the dongle that originally came with it. Trying to find some alternative, I found out, that the device uses some kind of connector I can't identify, and thus cannot even reverse engineer the dongle myself.

If somebody has a clue about what this connector could be, I would be really grateful.
The connector has 12 pins with HDMI (on the right of the connector for a comparison) like shape, but it is not a HDMI connector.

[image]

Here is the connector from the front
[image]

Here is the connector from the top
[image]

The dimensions are (cca):

- width: 8.3 mm
- height: 2.05 mm
- depth: 7.15 mm
- length between first and last pin on the pcb: 6.6 mm

EDIT:

I just found out that the same cable is used with the Ezcap 284, but still have no clue about what the connector is and where to get one

This is how the Ezcap dongle looks like, pretty similar to that one from AverMedia:

[image]

Comment: A vendor specific connector for the component breakout to fit the card. Will need the cable that you seem to have identified. Ask AverMedia support for details - or look in used market places.

Comment: Did both without any luck. AverMedia just asked me if I have proper drivers installed *facepalm* I would rather pull this connector out and replace it with some similar, that will have the available counterpart.

Comment: Oh that dongle is just wires I bet, no smarts at all. I would just start injecting video and audio signals onto the board at that connector while monitoring the output stream.

Comment: Yes, that is probably what I would do. It makes perfect sense for the wiring, there are 12 pins, 2 shorted to ground. I bet the signal would be carried over 2 pins balanced for each signal. So I might just try to temporarily connect a video source to see if it works. Thanks!